# Brouwer’s fixed point theorem ⇒ Sperner’s lemma

Tags: discrete-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalence of Brouwers fixed point theorem and Sperner's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176547/equivalence-of-brouwers-fixed-point-theorem-and-sperners-lemma)

Does anyone know a *combinatorial* proof of the implication from Brouwer’s fixed point theorem to Sperner’s lemma?

See also [Equivalence of Brouwers fixed point theorem and Sperner's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176547), the same question for a proof in general (not necessarily combinatorial).

Comment: I have removed the "proof-writing" tag from this question.

Comment: Neither of the references is to a combinatorial proof.

Comment: That makes sense. If this question is closed as a duplicate, you can indicate on the original that you want a combinatorial proof. Separately, neither of the two questions (nor your comments on the other one) says that you are looking for any particular kind of proof, so those responding have no way to know.

Comment: As @Carl said. I reflected the intention of finding a combinatorial proof in the question and also linked to the original question.